# Apache .htaccess regex for GET param

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a similar rule in my .htaccess

> RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /?name=$4&year=$1&monthnum=$2&day=$3

Example

> http://www.example.com/news/2014/02/25/stackoverflow-is-cool/

Now I am required to add in extra parameter at the back such that it looks like

> http://www.example.com/news/2014/02/25/stackoverflow-is-cool/?source=email

I wish to get the `source` value and I tried the following:

> RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/**([^/]*)/\?source=(.*)**$ /?name=$4&year=$1&monthnum=$2&day=$3&source=$5

but it's not working. Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot access get parameters like that, since they are simply not part of the pattern you match your regex against. Please take a look at the excellent documentation of the rewriting module, this is explained in detail in there: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, can you please give it a try

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /?name=$4&year=$1&monthnum=$2&day=$3 [QSA]
```

The [QSA] Query String Append flag will retain the existing query strings. So your query string

http://www.example.com/news/2014/02/25/stackoverflow-is-cool/?source=email

Should get converted to

```
/?source=email&name=$4&year=$1&monthnum=$2&day=$3
```

Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/\?$ /?name=$4&year=$1&monthnum=$2&day=$3&source=$5
```

When you get source value..... just use

```
$SrcVal = str_replace('source=','',$_GET['source']);
```

Comment: I tried this one exactly before. But the GET param isn't matched by the regex at all. Thanks for answering though =]